# who wins if everyone has a pair

Tags: rules

I've been playing poker with friends and by the end of the play when all 5 cards are face up, everyone reveals their hand but only one of their cards matches the table, who is the winner? Table 5,9,K,6,A    Hand 1: 5,2 Hand 2: 9,J Hand 3: K,Q Hand 4: 8,6  Hand 5: J,A

Comment: Repeat this 100 times until it really sinks in: poker hands have five cards. EXACTLY five cards. No more, no fewer. A one-pair hand is judged by the pair, and then each of the three others. Two pair hands are compared by high pair, then low pair, then fifth card. And so on... Exactly five cards, every case, no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to see who's pair is the best in that case J,A wins.
You always play the 5 best cards so in this case the best hands of each player is

- Hand 1: 55 AK9 (one paire of 5)
- Hand 2: 99 AKJ (one pair of 9)
- Hand 3: KK AQ9 (one pair of K)
- Hand 4: 66 AK9 (one pair of 6)
- Hand 5: AA KJ9 (one pair of A)

Since Player 5 has a pair of Aces it is considered higher than player 3 with pair of Kings so player 5 would take the whole money in the pot.

You didn't mention which suites they had so i guess no one had a flush. If someone did it would be a different case because flush wins over any pair.

Let's see a situation where 2 players would win.

Let's say a board is AAJJ9

Player 1 has 88 
Player 2 has 52

Since the best hand for both players are the cards that are on the table. Player 1 pair of 8 means nothing because his best hand are the double pair in the board. Since player 2 also plays the board both players having the same hand split the money in the pot.

For player 1 to win he would need at least one of both his cards bigger than 9. he could have T,2 which than he would have AAJJT as his 5 best card combination.

It's pretty easy to understand once you get a hang of it. So basically first you see who has the best combination strength (high card,pair,double pair,trips,straight,flush etc...) If both players have the same strength combination you than see who's got the best out of the 5 card combination.

Answer (score 1):

Any Pokerhand consists of 5 Cards. These 5 cards are the best Cards of all the 7 Cards (5 Board + 2 Hand).
The Order of Hands is (Best to worse)

1. Royal Flush (10-A Street of 1 Color)
2. Straight Flush (any Street of 1 Color)
3. 4 of a kind (for Example 6 6 6 6)
4. Full House (3 of a kind + a pair)
5. Flush (5 cards of one Color)
6. Straight (5 cards)
7. 3 of a Kind
8. 2 Pair
9. 1 Pair
10. nothing

If 2 Players have the same Hand (for example 3 of a Kind) , the Player with the highest 3 of a kind wins.
If 2 Players have a Flush with Hearts (5 cards with a heart on it), the Player with the highest heart card wins. When players share the highest card, the second highest card count...
Board is Ah Jh 7h 4 2
Hand 1 is Kh 6h (best hand Ah Kh Jh 7h 6h) (win because of Kh)
Hand 2 is Qh 9h (best hand Ah Qh Jh 9h 7h)

If these Hands are the same (Board is J J A 3 4, Hand 1 is J Q , Hand 2 is J 9):

Best Hand for Hand 1 is:  J J J A Q (5 Cards)
Best Hand for Hand 2 is:  J J J A 9 (5 Cards)

So both have 3 J. But Hand 1 wins because of the Q.
if both players have J Q, the whole pot is split between those 2 Players.

Comment: there's no nothing in winning. (10. should be "high card") if no one has a pair the highest combination of cards wins.

Answer (score -3):

highest pair or high card. if the the players have same value then the pot is split.

Comment: Poker hands have five cards, no more, no fewer. One pair hands compare the pair, then each of the three unpaired cards in order. All five cards play in every hand. No exceptions.